# PHP foreach loop is being rendered before string concatenation

Tags: php, html, foreach

I'm trying to render some components inside of an `<article>`.

Hello World component:

```php
//components/HelloWorld.php
<?php //some comments ?>
<h1><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></h1>;
```

Foo component:

```php
//components/Foo.php
<?php //some comments ?> 
<?php echo 'Foo'; ?>;
```

My Class:

```php
//Render_Content.php

class Render_Content {

    public $content_components;

    function __construct($args) {

        $this->content_components = $args['content_components'];

    }

    private function loop_components($components) {
        foreach($components as $component):
            require 'components/' . $component . '.php';
        endforeach;
    }

    public function render_content() {
        $rendered_content = '<article>';
        $rendered_content .= $this->loop_components($this->content_components);
        $rendered_content .= '</article>';

        echo $rendered_content;
    }

}
```

My file:

```php
//myfile.php

$args = array(
    'content_components' => ['HelloWorld', 'Foo']
);
$content = new Render_Content($args);
$content->render_content();
```

What I'm expecting to happen is this:

```html
<article>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
</article>
```

What's happening is this, though:

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h1>Foo</h1>
<article></article>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The strings in your components will not concatenate, since you `echo` it. If the components are plain HTML, just keep them as HTML and use `file_get_contents` and concat the return. Otherwise, e.g. swap `echo` with `$html` and concat as necessary.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer @MarkusAO! In fact, my components are note plain HTML. I was trying to simplify the example and I didn't know that the echo could be a problem. I Edited the question. Using `file_gets_content` bring the raw file.
I'll keep looking. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ob_start(); require("otherfile"); return ob_get_clean();`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @NiettheDarkAbsol in the comments this code will work.

```php
//Render_Content.php

class Render_Content {

    public $content_components;

    function __construct($args) {

        $this->content_components = $args['content_components'];

    }

    private function loop_components($components) {
        ob_start();
        foreach($components as $component):
            require 'components/' . $component . '.php';
        endforeach;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function render_content() {
        $rendered_content = '<article>';
        $rendered_content .= $this->loop_components($this->content_components);
        $rendered_content .= '</article>';

        echo $rendered_content;
    }

}
```